# Is there a way to turn off boost date and time validation

Tags: c++, boost

I've been profiling our code and have noticed that a lot of time is being spent in boost time and date functions. It seems that the majority of this time is spent validating that number are within range and valid. Is there a compiler option that can turn off this validation to increase the performance of the boost date time function?

Comment: Look at the code that executes the "time and date functions" and see if you can find some `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` around it. Happy hacking!!

Comment: @RaydelMiranda that sounds like exceptionally bad advice. Instead, look at the docs and find out which methods perform the validation (e.g. copy constructors likely won't). Now, see whether you can write recurring tasks using those API members

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way to circumvent this.

The validation is unconditional and by design. But it happens only when required (when receiving input from external sources). The rest of the time, invariants in the code base remove the need for re-validation.

(See e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_intro for relevant documentation quotes)

Of course, you might try to

- avoid parsing dates/times from input where possible
- avoid converting to/from boost datatime types where possible

In particular, if this became a bottleneck, likely you are

- parsing a lot of input (in which case I'd argue that the validations are just required and a Good Thing(TM)
- perhaps using Boost Datetime inefficiently (e.g. if you use C api's like `localtime()` and convert the result to Boost types. In such cases, prefer to use boost clocks as the source of time (e.g. `second_clock::local_time()` or `gregorian::day_clock()`)